# BautifulSoup - How to find exact match for div names

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

How do I find exact matches for div names. It seems by default the below returns anything with col in the div name. Thanks

divs = player_soup.find_all( 'div', {'class': 'col'})

Answer (score 0):

Exact match = divs = player_soup.select( 'div[class="col"]')

Answer (score 0):

player_soup.find_all('div', class_='col')